# using a bottom tab bar from react navigation and move it to the side

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Does anyone know how to use the react-navigation bottom tab and move it to the side? or if not, has anyone done that? what was the implementation you used? I'm trying to fix a side bar similar to a bottom tab bar but on the side. thanks

Answer (score 2):

React navigation lets you create your own
[Custom navigator bar](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-navigators/).

They even have an example with most of the necessary code.
You just have to change the flex-direction of the container.